# How to list groups with gid in redhat?

Tags: rhel, command

I first listed the groups using :

```
groups
```

I added group using

```
groupadd -g 300 oinstall
groupadd –g 500 dba
```

and then when I do

```
groups 
root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel sfcb
```

I am unable to find groups I added. How to list groups with group id?
Also, if I try to add it again it says groups is already present.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The `groups` command lists groups that the user is currently a member of, not all the groups available on the system. You can lookup a group by name or gid using the `getent` command.

```
getent group oinstall
getent group 500
```

To show all the groups, just leave your search query off of the command:

```
getent group
```

Comment: why is it not showing the groups with groups command?

Comment: @Kitex because you created the group but you are not a member of it. You need to add your user to the group then logout and log back in for it to show up with the `groups` command.

Comment: that means I need to be the part of group? But I am logged in as root.

Comment: I think you are missing the first sentence of my answer. "The groups command lists groups that the user is currently in".

Comment: @kitex I updated to wording slightly, hope that helps you understand.

Comment: Also be aware that for `groups` to show a newly added group, the affected user have to log out and in.

Comment: @jordanm how would i list all the groups ?

Comment: @Kitex updated the answer

Comment: @jordanm marked as answer. you are owesome.

Comment: @jordanm this would be a separate question but, how did you get so good at linux?

Comment: @kinkajou lots of professional experience as well as a lot of time spent on sites such as this one and IRC Linux support. I have been a professional and an enthusiast for about 8 years. I think being an enthusiast is an important part because you are more likely to remember things that you care about.

Comment: @jordanm Agreed to heart !

Comment: you can use newgrp to start a new shell, and add your self to a group (If you are permitted to be in the group).

Comment: @kinkajou I used Gnu/Linux for all of my computing at home. Desktops, laptops, raspberry-pi's. I have been using it since 1991 (originally Gnu on Solaris, Dec, HP). I keep adding to my knowledge; No need to through it away, and start again (as with Microsoft's Windows).

Answer (score 11):

You can list groups by using `getent` or if not present, look in `/etc/group`

When running the command, the GID is the third value in the output, e.g:

```
$ getent group
man:x:15:
audio:x:63:
nobody:x:99:
users:x:100:
<--snipped-->
utmp:x:22:
```

So to only list groupnames and their GID, use `awk` to print the columns you want like this:

```
$ getent group | awk -F ":" '{ print $1,$3 }'
man 15
audio 63
nobody 99
users 100
<--snipped-->
utmp 22
```

See also http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html

In the case that `getent` is not present.

`$ grep $group /etc/group`

The GID is the 3rd value in the output. E.g

```
$ grep users /etc/group
users:x:100:
```

In the above, the GID for the group users is 100.
To only get group name and GID, you can use awk and grep like this:

```
$ cat /etc/group | awk -F ":" '{ print $1,$3 }' 
man 15
audio 63
nobody 99
users 100
<--snipped-->
utmp 22
```

Be aware that for systems set up to use external authentication (like LDAP), all groups will not be present in the /etc/group file.
See also http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/

Comment: Groups are not always stored in `/etc/group`. They could be stored in NIS, LDAP, etc.

Comment: Do not work with ldap group, use `getent group`.

Comment: For NIS, use `ypcat group`. For LDAP, `getent group` may work -- LDAP has to be configured to work with getent, otherwise it will only show the contents of /etc/group. $0.02